# Testing PrimeNG Table Lazy Loading

Tags: angular, jasmine, primeng

I have created a primeNG table as follows:

```
        <p-table 
            #dt
            [value]="auditTable"
            [lazy]="true"
            [customSort]="true"
            [globalFilterFields]="['entryDate', 'user', 'action', 'details']"
            [filterDelay]="1"
            (onLazyLoad)="onPageEvent($event)"
...
        </p-table>
```

The lazy loading function is implemented as follows:

```
  onPageEvent(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    this.options = {
      pageSize: event.rows,
      pageNumber: event.first / event.rows + 1,
    };
    this.options.sortField = (event.sortField) ? event.sortField : null;
    this.options.sortDirection = (event.sortOrder && event.sortField) ? event.sortOrder.toString() : null;
    this.options.search = (event.globalFilter) ? event.globalFilter : null;
    this.loadData();
  }
```

I need to test the `onPageEvent(event: LazyLoadEvent) {` event handler, specifically the parts highlighted in yellow, to improve test coverage:

[image: branch coverage missing in yellow]

Can you please provide a code example in Jasmine that would:

- simulate a `onPageEvent(event: LazyLoadEvent);` event
- cover the yellow parts

Thanks.

Comment: It's trivial to cover these lines since the source code of the table component is available: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/table/table.ts. Is there a specific problem you have?